# Replacing internal antenna cable for hp 15-r205nl

Tags: wireless-networking, antenna

As I said in the title I need to replace the internal antenna cable of my hp 15-r205nl laptop.
I've already removed the broken one.

[image: photo1]

[image: photo2]

The connector is a standard PCIe wireless adapter connector.
I've searched a lot on different sites, I've found some antenna cable with the same connector but for all of them the copper plate shape is different.
My question is the copper plate shape is relevant for compatibility or the only thing that matter is the connector?

Here an example of an antenna cable that I've found:

[image: antenna example]

Wireless adapter: Realtek RTL8723BE 802.11 bg

I know that I can use an USB adapter, but if possible I want an internal one.

Comment: The connection to the card is called "U.FL".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the shape. As long as the new antenna fits into your display and the cables have the right 
length (not too short, but also not much too long), you should be fine. Make sure the connector is the same! There are two variants, a "normal" and a "tiny" version. I guess you have the "normal" version.

As you've already disassembled the display, have a look at the dimensions of the (possible) new antenna and evaluate if it would fit if it's slightly bigger or different in shape.

Comment: Okay another question, in the antenna that i've removed there is, in addition to the copper plate, an adhesive black stripe (that was attached to the laptop). In the antenna in the third photo there isn't the black stripe, it's a problem?

Comment: In the third photo you have some adhesive from manufacturer 3M. As long as the antenna fits and you are able to attach it where it belongs it should be okay. I use double sided tape (car industry) for such things.

Comment: Freddy's absolutely right; if it fits abd is near to the original length, it will work OK.